# countability of the set of discontinuities

Tags: real-analysis

Is the set of discontinuities (points where our function is discontinuous) for a monotone function countable even if it's defined on an unbounded interval if so why?

Comment: FYI, a subset of the reals cannot be uncountable without being uncountable in some bounded interval. In fact, any uncountable set of reals is such that there exists a nested and decreasing sequence of intervals whose lengths approach zero and the set has uncountable intersection with each interval in that sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Let's suppose without loss of generality that the function $f$ is increasing. Since the function is monotone we know that it has finite one sided limits at every point. So a point $x_0$ is a point of discontinuity if and only if $\lim_{x\to x_0^-}f(x)<\lim_{x\to x_0^+}f(x)$. So for any point of discontinuity $x_0$ we can choose a rational number in the interval $(\lim_{x\to x_0^-}f(x), \lim_{x\to x_0^+}f(x))$. Since the function is monotone we know that if $y_0>x_0$ then $\lim_{x\to y_0^-}f(x)\geq \lim_{x\to x_0^+}f(x)$, hence the choice of rational numbers I described gives us an injection from the set of discontinuities of $f$ into $\mathbb{Q}$. And $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

The only type of discontinuity for a real-valued monotone function is a jump discontinuity.

Assuming your function is a map $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, there can be at most countably many such jumps since each jumped set contains an open interval, the jumped sets are all pairwise disjoint, and the union of the jumped sets is contained in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: what are you referring to with "jumped set"?

Comment: @FrançoiseNicolas : I suppose the set jumped by $f$ at $x$ would be $[\sup_{y\leq x}f(y),\inf_{y\geq x}f(y)]\setminus\{f(x)\}$  if $f$ is increasing, with appropriate changes if $f$ is decreasing. Note it's empty if $f$ is continuous at $x$, and otherwise is either an interval or two abutting intervals; each component of the jumped set contains an open interval. $$ $$Intuitively, it's the "gap" at $x$, realizing that $f(x)$ could sit in the middle of this gap (as with the signum function at $0$).

Comment: Correction: I guess that should be strict inequality in the sup and inf, @FrançoiseNicolas